# How do I create an equality test for a custom class in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do I create an equality test for a custom class in Swift to test if two objects of the same custom class point to the same thing?

```
class MyClass : Equatable {

}

func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs // What should go in here to test if they both point to the same memory space?
}

let obj1 = MyClass()
var obj2 = obj1

if (obj1 == obj2) {
  println("same object")
}
```

Comment: it seems like you mix up equality `==` and identity `===`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the identity operator (`===`) instead. When used on objects it checks to see if they point to the same instance.

```
class MyClass {}

let obj1 = MyClass()
var obj2 = obj1

if (obj1 === obj2) {
    println("same object")
}
```

It also means you don't have your class implement any extra protocols. All classes have this behavior. You could still override `==` if you want though. Just use `return lhs === rhs` in your `==` function.

Comment: I tried the code and it doesn't print "same object".  Any idea why - aren't the two pointing to the same object?

Comment: Are you running it in a playround?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that. I tested my code in a playground and it worked fine

Comment: Are you sure you're using that exact code? I just tried in a command line project and it works fine

Comment: My mistake, I had a typo in there.  Could you upvote the question? It's a legit question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56070/discussion-between-boon-and-connor).